# Find differences in two rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that I am using to track staff record changes.
I also have a report that shows staff that have had a change AND staff that don't have a value in their "manager" field.

What this means is - 
If Manager is null - a staff member will appear in the report - and MAY only have 1 row.

If a staff member has had a change during the reporting period, they will have two rows in the report.
The oldest change from the reporting period and the CURRENT state.

The SQL is used to populate a web page.
The report looks like this;
(I have deliberately kept it simple in the example)

```
ID   StaffName  Manager field3  field4  field5  field6  enddate
104  Mathew     Gavin      A       A       A      A     '2015-03-01'
107  Mathew     Gavin      B       A       A      A     NULL
89   Gavin      Lachlan    A       A       A      A     '2015-03-01'
100  Gavin      Lachlan    A       B       A      A     NULL
123  Gus                   A       A       A      A     NULL
178  Mark                  A       A       A      A     NULL
```

Gavin has had a change and so appears twice in the report.
Only the second row (where enddate is not null) is editable.

Gus and Mark appear in the report, because they have no Manager assigned 
and they are both editable - which is correct.

However, Mathew should NOT appear in the report.
Which is my problem that I need a hand with.

At the moment my SQL returns all staff regardless of the change they have had.
But I ONLY care if the change is in  one of the following columns;
Manager or Field4 or 5.
A change in Field3 (or 6) does NOT warrant Mathew's inclusion in the report.

Here is the SQL that I am using, limited to the fields that I have provided in the example data.

```
SELECT
    distinct *
FROM
    (
    -- get LATEST ROW where NOT CLOSED
    SELECT 
        pg1.id, 
        pg1.lastname, 
        pg1.firstnames, 
        pg3.firstnames + ' ' + pg3.lastname AS Manager,
        pg4.activeStartDate, 
        pg4.activeEndDate
    FROM
        pgEmployees pg1
            LEFT JOIN pgEmployees pg3 ON pg3.id = pg1.managerId
    WHERE 
        pg1.id in 
        (
        Select Distinct ID From pgEmployees
        Where activeEndDate is null
        AND
        (activeStartDate between '#lsdateformat(arguments.startDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")# 00:00:00.000' and '#lsdateformat(arguments.endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")# 23:59:59.999')
      )

    --GET THE LATEST OLD ROW
    UNION 
        SELECT
            pg4.id, 
            pg4.lastname, 
            pg4.firstnames, 
            pg5.firstnames + ' ' + pg5.lastname AS Manager,
            pg4.activeStartDate, 
            pg4.activeEndDate
        FROM
            pgEmployees pg4
            LEFT JOIN pgEmployees pg5
                ON pg5.id = pg4.managerId
            INNER JOIN(
                SELECT 
                    adUserId,
                    max(id) id
                FROM 
                    pgemployees
                WHERE
                    activeEndDate IS NOT NULL   
                AND
                    activeEndDate < '#lsdateformat(arguments.endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")# 23:59:59.999'
                GROUP BY
                    adUserId
            ) SubQ ON (
                pg4.adUserId = SubQ.adUserId and pg4.id = SubQ.id
            )
        WHERE
            (pg4.activeStartDate < '#lsdateformat(arguments.endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")# 23:59:59.999' or pg4.activeStartDate is null)
        AND
            (pg4.activeEndDate IS NOT NULL) 
        AND
            (pg4.activeEndDate < '#lsdateformat(arguments.endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")# 23:59:59.999')

    -- GET THE STAFF THAT HAVE NO MANAGER
    UNION 
        SELECT 
            pg6.id, 
            pg6.lastname, 
            pg6.firstnames, 
            NULL AS Manager,
            pg6.activeStartDate, 
            pg6.activeEndDate
        FROM
            pgEmployees pg6
        WHERE
            (pg6.managerAD IS NULL)
        AND
            (pg6.activeEndDate IS NULL)
    )Subq
ORDER BY
    lastname ASC, 
    firstnames ASC,
    id;
```

Comment: Hi Luke,
I just have the original one. It is redicuously large on account of the number of fields that I am retrieving and the fact that I have a union in it to retrive the accounts where there is no manager defined, too. I can post it - but it is a monster and I thought It would just make the original post too awful to get some help from.
Thus the simple example (by data).

Comment: Could you adapt your query to the data sample you've posted? Perhaps it wouldn't be too large then, although I don't know what kind of approach you are trying there, of course. Also, I have a problem with this paragraph: `Gavin has had a change and so appears twice in the report. Only the second row (where enddate is not null) is editable.` In Gavin's second row, `enddate` *is* null actually, according to your example. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, I think it's best to give the query. Remember to remove personal data, secret keys, etc before posting! :)

Comment: @andrily: no row is updated. The original is closed and a new row produced that is the true reflection of the data, now. A closed row signifies the old state of the data. The SQL drives a web page, the web page has logic in it that says "provide a Edit hyperlink for any row in the report that does not have an EndDate. The outcome of which is the current row is closed and a new one inserted with the new data,

Comment: Hi Gavin, your instinct to store multiple rows per change is correct, logging a change rather than updating a row has advantages. However, it doesn't make sense to close rows by using the date field. The correct way to do this is to capture the timestamp on change, and then lag the records to get the latest record for each employee. This change date could start at the time of insertion, and increment on each change. This way you are keeping a true chronological record of each change.

Comment: Hi Johnny  I am doing what you suggested already.  What i need is sql help so as to only retrieve recirds where the chsnge is in a particular group of columns and not jyst s change - anywhere - which is wgat I currently have.

Comment: Seems like you just need to filter rows with an EXISTS() clause that checks to see if only the columns you want to consider have changed.

Comment: Hi Tab, I could be wrong - and thats why I am asking for help.... But I can't see how I can use the exists() function to compare the value of columns between rows. I need to check if the previous row is the same staff member and also check if Manager. field4 and field5 are the same or different and then only show "both" rows - if current.staffid = previous.staffid AND (previous.manager <> current.manager OR previous.field4 <> current.field4 OR previous.field5 <> current.field5). How do I get all that using exists()?